# System.Threading.Task does not contain definition

Tags: c#, multithreading

I cant have .Delay definition on my System.Threading.Task.

```
 public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()
 {         
     await Task.Delay(10000);
     return "Finished";
 }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are using .NET 4. Back then, there was no `Task.Delay`. However, there was a library by 
Microsoft called [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/), and it provides an alternative: `TaskEx.Delay`.

It would be used like this:

```
public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()
{         
    await TaskEx.Delay(10000);
    return "Finished";
}
```

Your other options are to either update to .NET 4.5, or just implement it yourself:

```
public static Task Delay(double milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

(taken from Servy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342256/1822164)).

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret the question correctly, it sounds like you are simply using .NET 4.0; `Task.Delay` was added in .NET 4.5. You can either add your own implementation using something like a system timer  callback and a `TaskCompletionSource`, or: just update to .NET 4.5